# list only stores last iteration

Tags: python, dataframe

The last iteration of the code is getting stored in the dataframe "df1". I am trying to create a list which which shows the result of each iteration in a row. For example: iteration 1 in row 1, iteration 2 in row 2, etc...

I have forgone to include the computations for the variables as it not relevant to the problem. Any ideas how to best approach this?

I have tried to change the indentation and use a for loop within the the current "for path in all_possible_path" loop.

```
for i in range(4):
    count = range(i)

 shortest_path= None
    shortest_path_length = None
    for path in all_possible_path:
        fullpath = u + s + d
        euclidean_length = total_distance(fullpath)
        print("Path: {} has total length:{}".format(fullpath, euclidean_length))
        df1 = [fullpath, euclidean_length]


        if shortest_path_length is None or shortest_path_length > euclidean_length:
            shortest_path_length = euclidean_length
            shortest_path = fullpath
```

I am not getting any error messages but there seems to be an issue with my setup. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I recommend that you back off from writing so much code at once.  Use incremental programming: write *one* step at a time; debug it before adding the next.  You're getting tied up with making several mistakes at once, which makes debugging *very* hard.

Comment: It's hard to help when you haven't posted the MCVE we expect.  However, I notice first that you have *not* created a data frame anywhere in this code.  You've assigned a list of two unknown elements to a variable `df1` -- and you overwrite that variable every time through the loop.  When you exit the loop. the only value left is the final one.

Comment: Work through tutorials on loop control, data frame creation, and any other concept that gives you trouble as you try to first use it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code with following. It should work if I understood your problem correctly.

```
for i in range(4):
    count = range(i)

 shortest_path= None
    shortest_path_length = None
    for path in all_possible_path:
        fullpath = u + s + d
        euclidean_length = total_distance(fullpath)
        print("Path: {} has total length:{}".format(fullpath, euclidean_length))
        df1 = df1.append([fullpath, euclidean_length]) // this is list of lists so it should keep data from each iteration.

        if shortest_path_length is None or shortest_path_length > euclidean_length:
            shortest_path_length = euclidean_length
            shortest_path = fullpath
```

Your data is now stored in `df1`. Please check it and lets us know.